# Is it possible to write below code in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Below code is possible to write or not. I tried does not getting exact result. I want know about the code result.

```
data = User::pluck('id','name')->where('id',$request->id);
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
$data = User::where('id', $request->id)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

It will give you a collection of one element with this structure:

```
[4 => 'John']
```

If you just need a name, use the `value()` method:

```
$name = User::where('id', $request->id)->value('name');
```

Comment: @ParamasivamRangasamy please describe what result exactly do you want to get.

Comment: upto my knowledge while pluck use.where condition does not work.you are giving answer (value () ) useful me.

Comment: i have doubt value method is not there.i see values() method in laravel

Comment: @ParamasivamRangasamy why don't you just run the code to see if it works? Also you can read about the `value()` method in [the Query Builder docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)

Answer (score 0):

where  should come before  get or pluck function

data = User::where('id',$request->id)->pluck('id','name');

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **why** and **how** this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write shortly

```
$data = User::whereId($request->id)->pluck('name','id');
```

Output

```
 [id=>name]  //return id and name like this array
```